# Construction "Create some, for exmaple, this way"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage

This about a tutorial in which an author tells to create some computer files if there is not any computer file in a specific computer folder. I am not sure if it is proper the sentence:
"If there are not any project files in a project directory, create some, for example, this way:"

First, can it be no noun after "some"? The noun is in one's mind.
Second, can "for example" be associated with a way of doing something? Usually, it is associated with nouns or adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some** is frequently used as a pronoun, as in:

> As we are short of apples, please get SOME from the market.

The noun **apples** is understood from the first half of sentence.

It's like saying:

> The new vacuum cleaners are brilliant; THOSE are what we need to clean the floor.

The phrase **for example** can be used to introduce any construction, whether just a noun, a phrase or a clause.

> You need to be aware of dangerous insects, for example, ticks.
>
> You need to be aware of dangerous insects, for example, small black ticks.
>
> You need to be aware of dangerous insects, for example, the small black ticks that you find in the long grass.